# Macbook Pro not Starting

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, startup, kernel-panic

I have a MacBook Pro and from the last week I have been unable to turn the machine on properly. First it displays the Apple logo and shows this message

[image: kernel panic]

I've done a lot of research and tried things like starting in [Safe Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1455). Although the error message does not come up, it will just hang at a grey screen with a spinning progress indicator.

If anyone can help, please share.

Comment: Did you try booting into recovery mode with Cmd-R?

Comment: Often we wake up but Computer won't.
We do everything to get it back alive.

One day Computer wakes up but we won't.
How about returning the favor.

Comment: nice thought Young man....!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [kernel panic](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3742) and will occur when your Mac cannot possibly continue operating, and can be caused by either hardware or software.

The easiest way to determine whether it's a hardware or software problem is to boot into [Recovery Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718). Restart your Mac and hold down <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> +<kbd>R</kbd> until the Apple logo appears on screen. If you see the following screen then there's a fair change the problem lies within the software of your Mac. You will probably need to [reinstall your OS](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10763).

[image: OS X Recovery mode]

[This article](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3742) has more steps you can go down to help isolate the issue

If you still get the same error when trying to boot into the alternate Recovery OS, that would indicate a problem with the hardware of your Mac. Try removing as many peripherals as you can and reseating the RAM.

In the event of a problem with your hardware, I would recommend you get in touch with an Apple Authorised Service Provider to take a look at your mac, or check out [Apple Support](http://www.apple.com/support/)

Comment: try but not responding on command + R .still hang

Comment: How old is your Mac? Do you have recovery media, such as the install CD or USB drive? Try holding down alt on boot to boot from that

Comment: No i di't try this.

Comment: Thank You For sharing Got the solution Hardware problem is there so need to go on Mac store .

Answer (score 2):

It sometimes is difficult to diagnose startup problems due to the variety of reasons (hardware issues, disk corruption, wrong configuration etc.). Apple has a bunch of support documents related to this topic:

- [Resolve startup issues and perform disk maintenance with Disk Utility and fsck](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1417)
- [Mac OS X: Gray screen appears during startup](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2570)
- [Mac OS X: How to start up in single-user or verbose mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1492)
- [OS X: About OS X Recovery](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718)

Comment: Thank You For sharing Got the solution Hardware problem is there so need to go on Mac store .